# multi-level Wilcoxon analysis

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

The question was originated from the paper [1] Table 3 [2], for every species, there was a data frame with two column: disease categories and the conservation index. Conservation index is numeric. The disease has 16 categories. As the authors described in their paper, the Table 3 was produced by doing 16-level Wilcoxon analysis. After a while googling, I still can't catch what is "multi-level Wilcoxon analysis". I wonder how were the standardized scores calculated? Are there R functions do this work?

**References**

[1] Huang, H., et al. (2004). "[Evolutionary conservation and selection of human disease gene orthologs in the rat and mouse genomes](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/gb-2004-5-7-r47)." *Genome Biol* 5(7): R47.

[2] https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/gb-2004-5-7-r47#Tab3

Comment: They use the phrase "two-level comparisons" I think to mean a two-sample Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney test.  The way it's presented, I don't know what the "16-level" test would be.  Have you tried asking the authors?

Comment: It is strangely worded. It almost sounds as though they conducted an omnibus Kruskal-Wallis test followed by Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney post hoc tests

Comment: @TPM - AFAICT, that's correct.

Comment: Following TPM and SalMangiafico, I guess the procedure to calculate the Table 3 is: 

1)  two-level one-tail Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney comparisons, i.e. one category VS all-other genes, got the p-value or the statistic (W) value; 

2) calculate -log10(pv) or directly using the statistic (W); 

3) if the values of the tested category are greater than the all-other genes, assign positive, else minus; 

4) calculate the normalized Zscore, should be the authored noted "Standardized scores", of the selected -log10(pv) or statistics (W).